# Razor pages loading a custom routed page inside a static page

Tags: .net, routes, razor-pages

I have static pages on my Razor pages project one of them for example is 
the About-us.cshtml which is inside the Pages folder (default)

Then I have this Page Route on the Startup.cs

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Listing", "{programType}/{city}");
```

When I load the site and open the about us page localhost/about-us then it loads teh about-us page correctly for 3 seconds later I get the Listing page loaded Inside the about us page (so it literally will add an extra top menu and footer.

For what I understand it is loading both pages, but I though that since the About-Us page (existing file with that name) already satisfied the route it should have stop processing rules.

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in your browser to see if that gives any clues?

Comment: I will check that, thanks for the advice, at the moment I ended up changing {programType} for the actual progams until I can fix the problem